# await-ed async Task with sleeping thread not being waited for

Tags: c#, async-await

In the below example, **BREAKPOINT-2** is only reached if I wait sufficiently long at **BREAKPOINT-1** (5 seconds or more). Otherwise, when `Main` exits, the program halts and `T1` never gets to complete. **Is it normal behavior for an `await`-ed `async` `Task` with a sleeping thread to not be waited for?**

```
public class Example
{
    private static Task T1()
    {
        return Task.Run(async () => 
        {
            // ManagedThreadId=N (N != 1)

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            int x = 1; /*BREAKPOINT-2*/
        });
    }

    public static async void Example1()
    {
        await T1();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        // ManagedThreadId=1

        Example1();
    } /*BREAKPOINT-1*/
}
```

Comment: You're not `await`ing `Example1()`, so execution blithely continues after submission.  This is besides the problem that you shouldn't be using `Thread.Sleep`, but instead doing `await Task.Delay(...)`.  Recent versions of C# can do [an `async Main()`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/30/c-7-series-part-2-async-main/)

Comment: Nothing in the Main to wait, make Main method too Async Await, and return only Task or Task<T>, no void

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/01/20/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj891052.aspx
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2015/09/10/tasks-are-still-not-threads-and-async-is-not-parallel/#comment-4375
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/06/15/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do void in the Example1 method it is telling it fire and forget.

> public static async void Example1()

change it to a task;

> public static async Task Example1()

then wait for it with

> Example1().Wait();

or if async method await